# Retrieve data from database as pdf file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My application use *Firebase*, how can retrieve the data from database as pdf file?
Users should be able to download that pdf file on their device.

Note: this code not related to my question

```
 public void addinfo() {
    HashMap<String, String> datamap = new HashMap<>();
    datamap.put("", ed1.getText().toString().trim());
    datamap.put("", ed2.getText().toString().trim());
    datamap.put("", ed3.getText().toString().trim());
    datamap.put("", ed4.getText().toString().trim());
    datamap.put("", ed5.getText().toString().trim());
    datamap.put("", ed6.getText().toString().trim());
    datamap.put("", ed7.getText().toString().trim());
    datamap.put("", ed8.getText().toString().trim());

    databasestudent.push().setValue(datamap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(Form4Activity.this, "done Successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Form4Activity.this, "erorr!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a cloud function that reads your database and creates a pdf from the data. The pdf could then be saved to storage and the storage url is then sent back to the client.

Comment: thanks sir ... can you share me with tutorial that can help me to solve my question ?

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way to Store The PDF file or any other file in Firebase Cloude Storage you can simply uplod a file using upload button

And Featching a file  by get Reference of the Firbase Storage using PDF view library

// get a child reference of file
 httpsReference = storage.getReference().child("xyz.pdf");

//and past the URL of file 
new RetrivePdfStreamJ().execute("https://xyz");

it Working for me